# How to get paragraph without editor points from mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to write a paragraph using editor as stackoverflow editors then send it in mysql database after I want to see it in my website again as I write. Actually I allready sent some paragraph using basic editor but in database I can see it with editor points(html tags). I can get the normal text paragraph But I don't know how can I get this kind of paragraph as I write.

Comment: What is your question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Have a look at CKEditor - there are several JavaScript HTML editors that can be integrated into a website.

Comment: This will close as off-topic presently. I advise that you give an editor system of some kind a go, and then explain if necessary what problems you are still having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CKEditor**

Read more about it [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation)

The steps to Integrate ckeditor with php pages are as follows

step 1 : Download the ckeditor.zip file

step 2 : paste ckeditor.zip file on root directory of the site or
you can paste it where the files are (i did this one )

step 3 : extract the ckeditor.zip file

step 4 : open the desired php page you want to integrate with here page1.php

step 5 : add some javascript first below, this is to call elements of ckeditor and styling and css
without this you will only a blank textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And if you are using in other sites, then use relative links for that here is one below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somedirectory/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

step 6 : next call the work code of ckeditor on to your page page.php
below is how you call it

```
<?php

// Make sure you are using a correct path here.
include_once 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php';

$ckeditor = new CKEditor();
$ckeditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
$ckeditor->editor('CKEditor1');

?>
```

step 7 : what ever you name you want, you can name to it ckeditor by changing the step 6 code last line

```
$ckeditor->editor('myCustomname');
```

step 8 : Open-up the page.php, see it, use it, share it and Enjoy because we all love Open Source.

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't advise answering questions as brief as this, which will close as off-topic. I hope you don't mind my asking, but have you copied this from another answer, or from elsewhere on the web? It is quite a lot to have typed in the two minutes since the question was asked.

Comment: @halfer, i actually had this answer already with me...

Comment: earlier i tried to answer a similar question and had this answer already prepared for that in my PC..saw a question which asked for that and posted it..

Comment: OK, well, my advice remains that a question this broad is best not encouraged with answers. We ask that OPs make _some_ effort here. (It is my experience that the OP usually has a more specific problem which is not yet stated, and much conversation will be needed to elicit the actual issue).

Comment: Yes @halfer i understood what you are saying..Sorry that i answered it..i just wanted to help him..should i delete this post?

Comment: @halfer Oh thankyou...last time also had some sort of similar issue and had to delete it..Thankgod that this tym I can post it as an answer.. ;) :)